# How to exclude cookies with express-winston?

Tags: javascript, express, winston

Reading at [express-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston) README it seems quire easy to remove the **headers** from logged line: we can simply act on `requestWhitelist` option, but this will disable all the headers from being logged.

Is there a way to disable only the `cookie` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you can create a custom filter like:

```
function customRequestFilter(req, propName) {
  if(propName !== "headers") return req[propName];

  const { cookie, ...rest } = req.headers;

  return rest;
}
```

And your winston options should be something like:

```
expressWinston.logger({
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
    // requestWhitelist: ['headers'],
    requestFilter: customRequestFilter,
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.colorize(),
      winston.format.json()
    ),
    meta: true, // optional: control whether you want to log the meta data about the request (default to true)
    msg: "HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}", // optional: customize the default logging message. E.g. "{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{res.responseTime}}ms {{req.url}}"
    expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting. Enabling this will override any msg if true. Will only output colors with colorize set to true
    colorize: false, // Color the text and status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (text: gray, status: default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red).
    ignoreRoute: function (req, res) {
      return false;
    }, // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
  })
```

I hope this could help you!
Cheers.

Comment: Apart from `customRequestFilter` could be simplified a lot (as I edited), exactly what I was looking for.